# ninject.extensions.factory on WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ninject, factory, ninject-extensions

I’m trying to use ninject.extensions.factory on WP8 but it seems to not work – I have no ToFactory() extension available . After looking at sources I see that everything is omitted when compiling on Windows Phone. Is there any way to use this extension and if not why is there WP compilation in builds?

Answer (score 1):

WP does not support the Emit Framework that is used internally by Castle Dynamic Proxy. The Factory proxies rely on this framework. Therefore the extension just supports Func and Lazy.

Unless someone comes up with dynamic proxy framework for WP this won’t ever be supported.